# Tomcat 7 CPU utilization is always above 30%

Tags: centos, tomcat7

Im working on a migration from windows server to linux.
Installed Tomcat 7 on centos 7 server, and deployed 5 web applications(taken from windows). Applications are running fine.

I open only a terminal window, but top cpu shows 33-41% usage, while in windows it's under 15%.

top sample output

```
PID    USER   RES    %CPU  %MEM COMMAND
13331  tomcat 978.2m  39%  6.2%   java
```

Is think this an issue, how should I solve it.

Any suggestions please.

[image]

Comment: Can you _really_ compare both servers 1:1? Exact same hardware etc.? AFAIK tomcat should perform about the same on Linux and Windows, with a slight benefit on Linux.

Comment: Check the settings of heap and eventually increase Xmx to 2GB (for example)